# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages - How to bind an asp-page-handler to a checkbox without Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I desperately try to bind and asp-page-handler to a checkbox. So that when the checkbox is clicked, a Page Handler is triggered. I don't want to have a button to submit, and I don't want to use JS. Because that is out of the sense of using ASP.NET and writing everything in C#. I know that there is a way to trigger the Page Handler with Ajax. But again, I do not want to have JS in my Web Page Project. Or at least just the minimum. Why? Because JS is the entry point for hacking. Look on PS4 and PS5 too. Therefore, I want to have as much as possible running on the backend. I search now for days and I couldn't find something that worked. I even tried to ask zzzcode.ai, but it seems she is pretty dumb on that subject. Everything she gave me, does either not work or it implements a button. A BUTTON FOR A CHECKBOX!!! Sorry. But, yea. A Button! Back to the subject: If there is no way to trigger the Page Handler from a Checkbox, then it's also okay. Else I have to use JS then. But I just can't believe that there is no way to trigger a OnCheckBoxClicked event to the backend site, without to use JS.

I can't even list here what all I tried the last days. But I will post a truncated snipet of the cshtml part, where I would like to have the checkbox to trigger a asp-page-handler.

```
<form method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-danger width-80-px i-fs-11 musr-del" type="submit" asp-page-handler="Delete">
        <i class="bi-person-slash"></i>
    </button>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.All" />  <!-- This Checkbox shall trigger a Method on the backend, when clicked. -->
                </th>
                .... <!-- Truncated -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        .... <!-- Truncated -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page handler is a server-side method that is executed as a result of an HTTP request. There are a number of ways to trigger HTTP requests, such as an anchor tag and a submit button in a form. Changing the state of a checkbox is not one of them.

So to confirm the result of your research - you need to hook into the change event of the checkbox with JS and use that to make the request.

As to JS being "the entry point to hacking" - there are plenty of entry points to hacking in web development. I recommend spending some time understanding the vulnerabilities and how to mitigate them through secure programming. A good starting point is the OWASP Top 10: https://owasp.org/Top10/

Comment: Interesting. Didn't expect that. Thanks for the confirmation and for the link. I'll have a good read on that page.